# GCC: Specifying static/dynamic libraries to build against

Tags: c++, c, boost, makefile

I have a simple C++ project that is structured as following:
-A base project (ie: contains main() ), and links against everything else
--A few custom libraries that are all built as static libs (ie: .a files)
---One of these static libraries uses features in a shared objective file (ie: a .so file)

So, for example, this is how the project would appear (in a a tree view) at link time, after all the initial compiling has completed:

```
-myApp            (the main application)
--libaudio.a      (the audio library I made)
--libnetwork.a    (the networking library I made)
--libvideo.a      (the video library I made)
--libboost.a      (boost library)
```

Initially, this project build just fine. I just had to make sure I had a simple line in my makefile like this:

```
LIBS+=audio network video
```

Recently, I had to change how my audio library works. I now am required to use a third-party library, and all I have is the header file (.h) and the shared object (.so) files. So the new structure at link time looks like so:

```
-myApp              (the main application)
--libaudio.a        (the audio library I made)
---libthirdparty.so (contains third-party audio handling functions)
--libnetwork.a      (the networking library I made)
--libvideo.a        (the video library I made)
--libboost.a        (boost library)
```

This, in effect, means that I have an application with a static library linked in which makes calls to an external shared object. So, I put the header file in the appropriate location so I don't have any build errors when compiling libaudio.a, and put the libthirdparty.so file in a location where the linker searches for all my installed libraries.

At this point, I cannot get the thing to build. It just doesn't see libthirdparty.so file, even though I know it is in a location that the linker searches by default. For some reason, wrapping my libaudio code, as in the example below (borrowed from www.cplusplus.com) fixes the build error:

```
my_C_CPP_Header.h:
#ifndef MY_C_CPP_HEADER
#define MY_C_CPP_HEADER

/*check if the compiler is of C++*/
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
int myOtherCfunc(int arg1, int arg2); /* a C function */
}
#endif

void myCppFunction1(); /* C++ function */
void myCppFunction2(); /* C++ function */

/*check if the compiler is of C++ */
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

Now, I have a new problem though. Now that it's building, it no longer statically links in libboost.a, and instead is crashing at startup due to libboost.so not being present. So, somehow this setup breaks how libboost is compiled in if I manage to get it to build at all.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You're not giving us much to go on. What "wrapping" did you add? (You seem to have an extra closing brace there.) And what command do you use to link? And how did you modify the makefile to deal with this new library?

Comment: I wrapped the header file (ie: libthirdparty.h) in:  #ifdef cplusplus extern c { ........  }  #endif  .

Comment: *libthirdparty.h*, not "my libaudio code"?

Comment: That is correct, libthirdparty.h

Comment: The problem(s) you fixed by adding `extern "C"` wrappers is apparently because the third party library has C API but the headers you got from them haven't been made C++ compatible - the wrappers you added make them so. To help with the problem that seems to cause with the boost library, the linker log provided if you add the `-Wl --verbose` option might help.

Comment: By the way, on systems I've used there usually isn't a single `libboost.a` that covers boost as a whole - the libraries provided by boost are usually specific to a particular functional area of boost, such as `libboost_serialization.so.1.42.0` or `libboost_regex.a`. Have you built your boost library in an unusual way?

Comment: Yes, I have built the library in a less than usual way (required to, ugh). I think I might have this solved soon. I will post updates as they come along, as I'm not at liberty to post the actual build output. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, there was a "LIBPATH=" instead of a "LIBPATH+=" statement overriding the library include paths. Resolved.

Thank you all for your help.